# How to refresh my DataGridView? I am trying to refresh the list in datagridview but i can't

Tags: c#

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PetsHotelSystem.User_Control
{
    public partial class UC_UpdateRoom : UserControl
    {
        function fn = new function();
        string query;

        public UC_UpdateRoom()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UC_UpdateRoom_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            query = "select * from rooms";
            DataSet ds = fn.getData(query);
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(txtRoomNo.Text != "" && txtType.Text != "" && txtBed.Text != "" && txtPrice.Text !="")
            {
                string roomno = txtRoomNo.Text;
                string type = txtType.Text;
                string bed = txtBed.Text;
                Int64 price = Int64.Parse(txtPrice.Text);

                query = "insert into rooms (roomNO, roomType, bed, price) values ('" + roomno + "','" + type + "','" + bed + "','" + price + "')";
                fn.setData(query, "Room Added.");

                UC_UpdateRoom_Load(this, null);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fill all fields.", "Warning !!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}```
````

Running the above piece of code returns the following error:

> WARNING: Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
> System.Data.dll  Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL
> into column 'roomID', table 'myHotel.dbo.rooms'; column does not allow
> nulls. INSERT fails.  The statement has been terminated.

How to fix it?

Comment: There's a far easier way to work with datatables and datagridviews than this

Comment: You have an exception in your query, so your main problem is not refreshing your datagrid but your query.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `roomID` column in your table.
if you want it to be automatically increment when inserting a new row manually, you have to define it as Auto Increment in the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

You have an exception with your query so you have to resolve if first, but refreshing your datagridview after inserting a data, the code should be

```
UC_UpdateRoom_Load(sender, e);
```